# Better way to set the parent to an ancestor change set and get the content of the tip

Tags: mercurial

The best way I found was:

```
hg update -r0 -C #ancestor rev 0
hg revert -r tip --all
```

To illustrate the situation a bit:

```
hg init
echo "init" > a.txt
hg commit -A -m“init” a.txt #rev 0

echo "hello" > a.txt
hg commit -m"change"

hg update -r0 -C
hg revert -r tip --all
```

The interesting properties are `hg diff -r tip` is empty and `hg parent` is `changeset: 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that like this, but don't tell anyone:

```
hg debugsetparent 0
```

you might need to also do `hg debugrebuildstate` for the `hg stat` command to realize you pulled a switcharoo on it.

You didn't hear it from me though. :)

Comment: that, of course, assume you were already updated to `tip` in your working dir.  If not you need a `hg update tip` first.

Comment: Thanks. At least I know there is no better "public" solution. (It's debug so it can change, break, ...)

Comment: Yeah, and it's lacking the warnings one would expect for something like that if it was anything but debug.